# JDBC multithreading db access is slow

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java-8

I am working a project which using concurrency. There are X threads which are working in the app, performing same task which is basically load data from db and process it and send it to a queue for other worker threads to retrieve them and process further. We have made some changes in Database access, before PreparedStatement/Statement were not closed and it was a mess. We have saw a small change in the prcoessing time during the day, before App could process 5 million offers in 3-4 hours but it's struggling and it takes 6-8 hours. The change was not sudden but it grew slowly over time. I have started wondering if the change in db access could affect it. This is how it looks like currently:

each Repository implements IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository {

  Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;

  default PreparedStatement prepareStatement(ThreadLocal<PreparedStatement> tlPs, String query) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = tlPs.get();
    if (ps == null || ps.isClosed()) {
      ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
      tlPs.set(ps);
    }
    ps.clearParameters();
    return ps;
  }

  default <T> List<T> select(PreparedStatement ps, ResultSetMapper<T> mapper) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
      return mapper.map(rs);
    }
  }
```

Example of Repository for given schema ("master" schema):

```
public interface MasterRepository extends IRepository {

  @Override
  default Connection getConnection() {
    return DataSources.Master.connection();
  }

}
```

An example of implementation of MasterRepository:

```
public class ExampleRepository implements MasterRepository {

  private final ExampleResultSetMapper exampleResultSetMapper;

  public ExampleRepository() {
    this.exampleResultSetMapper = new ExampleResultSetMapper();
  }

  private final ThreadLocal<PreparedStatement> st = new ThreadLocal<>();

  private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * from xtable ";

  public List<ExampleEntity> getAll() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = prepareStatement(st, QUERY);
    return select(ps, exampleResultSetMapper);
  }

}
```

An of how the db connection is established:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class DataSources {

  @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
  public static class Master {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Connection> connection = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<PreparedStatement> stSetTimeoutPsDeo = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static Connection connection() {
      try {
        if (connection.get() == null || connection.get().isClosed()) {
          Properties properties = Container.AppProperties.instance();
          Connection newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            properties.getProperty("db.deo.connectionUrl"),
            properties.getProperty("db.deo.user"),
            properties.getProperty("db.deo.password")
          );
          connection.set(newConnection);
          if (stSetTimeoutPsDeo.get() == null || stSetTimeoutPsDeo.get().isClosed()) {
            stSetTimeoutPsDeo.set(connection.get().prepareStatement("SET wait_timeout=3600"));
          }
          stSetTimeoutPsDeo.get().execute();
        }
      }
      catch (SQLException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
      }
      return connection.get();
    }

  }
```

We are using:

- Java 8,
- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.12 dependency

I was wondering if perhaps using ThreadLocal<> might be slowing the processing. We are not closing PreparedStatement, instead we are wrapping them in the ThreadLocal<> to not re-create them every time.

Does anyone has any idea if the following implementation might be some burden on processing speed? Each thread calls DB X times, even 200 separate SQL queries are made, smaller and bigger, it varies a lot. if calling ThreadLocal.get() is slower than perhaps over those 200 queries it can add up quite a nice number of milliseconds and over 10000 records processing might extend by few seconds even?

Each thread has it's own connection and it's own PreparedStatement, it is not shared

Comment: A `ThreadLocal` is not slow, especially when comparing with an actual database operation. You are looking at the wrong end. Use profiling tools to analyze. Side note: Am I right that the purpose of `@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` is to generate a private constructor as if you wrote `private Master() {}` or `private DataSources() {}` in the classes? So you are using a code generation tool, complicating the build process for a saving of source code characters that is not even small but actually negative?

Answer (score 1):

There are some drawbacks in queuing and multi-threading.

- If the effort involved in processing a task is not much higher than the cost of enqueuing plus dequeuing, then I say "Don't queue it, just do it".
- At some threshold, "too many" threads will lead to no more performance gains.  Keep in mind that RAM, CPU, disk, network, locks, etc all get stressed when "too many" threads are running.
- A possible starting point for multi-threading is the number of cores in the computer.
- If the tasks are I/O-bound (and you don't have RAID striping), then multi-tasking is not helpful.
- Each thread *must* have its own DB connection.  If not, then you must provide locks so that the no two queries are running at the same time in the different threads.  MySQL is designed for multi-threading, *but only if it controls the threading*.
- Simple queries, with SSDs, can run in a single thread at about 1K/second.  With multiple connections, 10K QPS is probably possible.  (If you would like to share the main queries, I can elaborate.)
- In some situations, bundling multiple queries into a transaction (`BEGIN`...`COMMIT`) will improve throughput.  Ditto for throwing multiple queries into a Stored Procedure.  (Again, it would help to have a feel for the dataset and the actions being performed.)
- If the dataset (or at least the "working set") is bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, it *will be* I/O-bound.